# Android timer with a twist

Tags: java, android, timer, handler

I know how to make a regular timer with and without handler, however i prefer with handler, so if you could give your answer preferably with that, i'd appreciate it even more so :)

What i want to do is create a timer that starts after my postDelayed handler and it gives the user x amount of time to click on one of the buttons otherwise, they lose. Basically you have 1 second to click on one button otherwise you will lose hp(or something).

Heres an example task:

I have to make a color app, and there will come a text up with the name of a color. The user then have to press on the buttons/imagebuttons on which color is correct. Now the user has 1 second to click on one of the buttons otherwise he loses..

anyone know a tutorial, or example i could use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, consider the following `Handler` definition:

```
private static final int LOSE_GAME_EVENT = 1;

private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what) {
            case LOSE_GAME_EVENT:
                // Then the player has lost the game.
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

When the player clicks the button and starts the timer, you can post a `LOSE_GAME_EVENT` message to be executed after a 1 second delay like this:

```
mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(LOSE_GAME_EVENT, 1000);
```

If the user doesn't click the button before the 1 second is up, then the event will be executed and the player will lose the game. Otherwise, when the button is clicked you can remove the event from the handler (thus ensuring it won't be executed) like this:

```
mHandler.removeMessages(LOSE_GAME_EVENT);
```

Comment: Thank you :) short and elegant, just how i like it ^.-